# Scoping behavior around find_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a lot of records in a table that I'm trying to alter using find_each. My question is: if I have a scope with which I'm using a find_each and within the find_each I alter the value I was scoping on for some records, will those affected records be processed in the find_each as well? For example, if I do something like this:

```
User.where(classification: nil).find_each do |u|
    if u.age > 21
        u.update!(classification: "accepted")
        User.where(classification: nil).where(age > 21).each do |other|
            other.update!(classification: "rejected")
        end
    end
```

Would the other user records that I updated while processing a previous users still be processed in the find_each given that the value they were being scoped on has been changed?

Comment: Oh I think I'd have a unit test to make sure that wasn't happening, and then I'd know my code was correct, and was going to stay that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would end up in the find_each list after being updated.  It uses the primary key as the sort and wouldn't hit lower ids again in subsequent loops.

EDIT

Sorry - I see what you're asking now.  Yes, it would affect it.  Changing all the classifications so they are no longer nil would cause the outer loop to return no items on the second batch.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Does it mean other user objects (who's classification has now changed) will not be processed in the find_each?

Comment: Find each will grab objects in batches of 1000 where the id is greater than the last item in the earlier batch.  So, the second batch is a completely different query.  If the conditions change, that second query could return no results.  That's how I read it.